# Como passar uma matriz para um arquivo .txt - MATLAB

Tags: matriz, matlab

Estou lendo uma imagem `teste.jpg` pelo comando `imread` e tranformando-a numa imagem cinza pelo comando `rgb2gray`. Preciso dos códigos correspondentes do resultado dessa matriz, em um arquivo `.txt`.

Segue o Exemplo:

[Imagem teste http://dc.itamaraty.gov.br/imagens-e-textos/imagens-do-brasil/fauna/alta-fauna15.jpg/image_preview](http://dc.itamaraty.gov.br/imagens-e-textos/imagens-do-brasil/fauna/alta-fauna15.jpg/image_preview)

```
A = imread ('alta-fauna15.jpg') 
B = rgb2gray (A) 
imshow (A)  // Mostra Imagem colorida 
imshow (B)  // Mostra Imagem em escala de cinza
```

Preciso desses valores da matriz `B` em um arquivo `.txt`, como posso fazer isso?

Comment: Deu para perceber que esta pergunta foi criada através do celular, ou pelo menos parecia, porque a maior parte das palavras pareciam resultado do `auto-correct` xD

Answer (score 2):

Uma maneira fácil de fazer é transformando a imagem de 8-bit unsigned integers para double, e salvar usando dlmwrite().

```
A = imread ('alta-fauna15.jpg') 
B = rgb2gray (A) 
imshow (A)  % Mostra Imagem colorida 
imshow (B)  % Mostra Imagem em escala de cinza

dlmwrite('myFile.txt',im2double(B)); % Salva e converte 

C=dlmread('myFile.txt'); %Le o arquivo
C=imshow(C) %Mostra Imagem em escala de cinza

D=im2uint8(C); %Converte novamente para 8-bit unsigned integers
```